# Find usages for enums via Ctrl + left in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, enums

In IntelliJ I can very easily find usages of an enum constant by <kbd>Ctrl + left click</kbd> on an enum constant. However, if the enum implements a constructor, I'm going directly to that constructor instead.

I know I can also search for usages with <kbd>Alt + F7</kbd> but is it possible to always do that on <kbd>Ctrl + left click</kbd> even if there is a constructor?

Comment: You could add a mouse shortcut to Find Usages in `Settings | Keymap`.

Comment: I was searching for a solution to this problem as well. I know I had it set up, but I've reinstalled my OS and Android Studio, and now with the same shortcuts preset I cannot command+click into an enum member to find its usages. I was able to do it before :S

Comment: Funny, couple of years later (IDEA 2020) I've got the reverse problem. I don't know how to get from the enum constant to the constructor. Anything I do it's all about usages. :-)

Comment: Right, they seem to have changed the default behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 you can do both the `Go to constructor` and `Find usages` actions using simple shortcuts:

- `Go to constructor` - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left-click</kbd> on enum name. Or put the caret on it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
- `Show usages` - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left-click</kbd> at **the end** of enum name (between the last character of the name and the opening parenthesis). Or put the caret after the last character of the name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image: enum shortcut zones]

YouTrack issue about this behavior:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248865

Comment: In my case wherever I put the cursor to, it always only goes to constructor. 2021.2.3 Ultimate

Answer (score 3):

In the editor, select a symbol for which you want to see the usages. From the main menu, select **Edit | Find | Show Usages** **Ctrl+Alt+F7**. 
The usages window shows the current scope. If you want to quickly switch to the default scope, press Ctrl+Alt+F7

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-highlight-usages.html

Comment: Thanks for that, Ctrl+Alt+F7 is really helpful here!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like since IntelliJ IDEA 2020 the behaviour changed and shows usages on <kbd>Ctrl + left click</kbd> by default.

Comment: And how, then, go to the constructor?

Comment: My enums are simple enough so I didn't need that so far but anyway good question. I don't know.